# How to disable JPA entity management by default in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot + Data JPA and I've implemented few repositories. Right now, it seems that all entities are managed by JPA by default and making even slight local change for small operations is automatically reflected into the database which obviously I don't want.

Although we can detach the entity via EntityManager but doing it after every operation seems like a poor approach as I don't want entities to be managed at all.

Is there a way to globally disable Entity management using Bean config or some property?

Comment: That is the whole point of JPA, managed entities. Sounds like you don't want to use JPA as you don't want managed entities (then why use JPA at all).

Comment: I don't think "MANAGED ENTITIES" is the only way to use JPA as there are countless features of JPA that I'm using except this one.

Comment: Then detach them, as that is how it is supposed to wok (also this isn't a Spring Data JPA question but rather a general JPA question).

Comment: Exactly, detaching is a way. But I'm using the Repository of Spring Data. To detach, I have to create more DAOs that fetch data from the Repository and then detach them. Instead, I'm looking for more of a Spring-style way to handle detachment.

Comment: I don't understand why wyou would need more repositories to detach the data. There is not really a more spring way, unless you skip using transactions which will detach them. However I still don't see the point and feels you are using JPA where you shouldn't (or are using it in a wrong way, like modifying/clearing values before showing them on screen etc.).

Comment: I am using a plain repository without @Transactional annotation though.

Comment: If your service isn't transactional it will be already detached, so your service (or something else in your stack) is transactional. You also want to set the `spring.jpa.open-entitymanager-in-view` property to `false`.

Comment: You'll need to verify that the same EntityManager context isn't being reused. Everything read through an EntityManager is cached and managed by it, so that multiple reads give you back the exact same instance. If you modify an entity and don't want that instance returned on later queries - you'll probably want to demarcate your EntityManager via explicit detach calls, or just outright clear everything with clear() or by obtaining a new entityManager, so that your calls operate more like they would within a transaction for things you'll want to modify but not commit

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to apply the query hint `org.hibernate.readOnly` to configure the query to return the entities as read-only. Read-only entity has the following [behaviour](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setReadOnly(boolean)) :

> Read-only entities are not dirty-checked and snapshots of persistent state are not maintained. Read-only entities can be modified, but changes are not persisted.

In term of spring-data , you can annotate all query methods of your repositories by :

```java
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo,Integer> {

     @QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.readOnly", value = "true") })
     List<Foo> findSomeFoo();
}
```

If you need the same query method but returning non read-only entities in the future , you can create another one method but without annotating that query hints.